# From a list of active & expired policies: Show which have renewed and which have lapsed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is an example of my issue - I have a list of insurance policies, some are active and others expired. The data goes back quite a few years, so it's possible that a policy was first taken out in 2012, and renewed every year and currently has an active policy so will appear on the list every year from 2012 to 2018 - a total of 7 times; 6 expired and 1 active. I have the data in a power pivot model to give me the net-loss ratio of each individual policy as well as across all policies. What I want now is to be able to filter on active policies and have a full history of the policy rather than just the currently active year.

My current data looks like this:

```
**Policy Number**         **Status**

ABC11AA-2016               Expired

ABC11AA-2017               Expired

ABC11AA-2018               Active

ABC11SZ-2016               Expired

ABC11SZ-2017               Expired

ABC11JG-2017               Expired

ABC11JG-2018               Active

ABC11KR-2012               Expired

ABC11KR-2013               Expired

ABC11KR-2014               Expired

ABC11KR-2015               Expired
```

Essentially what I'm looking for is a third column with a formula that will tell me which expired policies have a currently active policy. I'm not interested in looking at expired policies that have not renewed. But it would be interesting to know how policies that are currently active have performed over their lifetime. I'm imagining a list similar to the one below.

```
**Policy Number**        **Status**           **Current Status**

ABC11AA-2016               Expired              Currently active

ABC11AA-2017               Expired              Currently active

ABC11AA-2018               Active               Currently active

ABC11SZ-2016               Expired              Not renewed

ABC11SZ-2017               Expired              Not renewed

ABC11JG-2017               Expired              Currently active

ABC11JG-2018               Active               Currently active

ABC11KR-2012               Expired              Not renewed

ABC11KR-2013               Expired              Not renewed

ABC11KR-2014               Expired              Not renewed

ABC11KR-2015               Expired              Not renewed
```

With this new column, my thought is to add it as a filter to my power pivot. I can then use this filter to return policies that are still active and have information on their long-term net loss ratios as opposed to current year only.

I've used LEFT(A2,7) to get the policy prefixes in a column of their own. And tried many different combinations of INDEX, MATCH, etc. to solve this problem but can't seem to crack it.

I hope this all makes sense. Your help is hugely appreciated - Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 2016 you can use `TEXTJOIN` in an array formula:

```
{=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Active",TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF($A$2:$A$12=A2,$C$2:$C$12,"")))),"Not renewed","Currently active")}
```

Activate the furmula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you!

A few notes for others who may use this formula for a similar problem:

It seems to fall apart when filtering on a table and the array formula has to be activated again and copied down. I worked around this by simply pasting values in a different column and will update the formula every time new information is added and re-paste values.

Also make sure your data is sorted correctly. For me I had to sort by Policy Number then Policy Year to ensure that if there is an Active policy, the Active status would be the last one found by the formula.

Comment: I didn't know that filtering or sorting the data would damage the activation. I made a test and you can avoid this issue if you use 'Format as Table' in 'Home' tab. This will keep the formula activate in each row and it will fill it out for new data automatically. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: The data was already formatted in a table. But thank you! The extra step is fine as it's only updated once per month. A couple of seconds are no bother.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the way to approach this is by looking at the year rather than the column prefixes. So in that instance you would be using the RIGHT function and looking at the last two digits.

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="18",B2,"")
```

The above formula (assuming the columns are in A,B,C[C2 is where this formula would be entered] respectively) puts a value in the column equal to the value in B if the year is 2018. This would return the most current status of said policies.

Without seeing how your pivot is set up, I imagine that you can pretty easily see the history of the policy.

Another option is to reformat the data slightly to make it easier to use. Let me know if the above works, if not, we can try slightly altering your data to suit.

Comment: The policies can be taken out at any point in the calendar year and would take that year as its suffix then run for 365 days. A policy taken out on 1st January 2017 would now be expired and have a new active policy starting 1st January 2018 with the 2018 suffix. However, a policy taken out 31st December 2017 would have the 2017 suffix and still be active as it would expire on 30th December 2018. As such, policies with the 2017 suffix could currently be active too; not just 2018 policies.

I'll be sure to provide more information going forwards. Thank you for your time and answer though :)